# Change the user in Skype

Tags: skype

I have several Skype accounts. How can I change the account used by the Android Skype app? I don't see a way to log off/log on. Should I de-install & re-install from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the secret is that there is a settings page but to get there you have to tap your avatar/icon at the top of the chats history. Then the "Disconnect from Skype" option is at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

According to [skype support](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12358/how-do-i-sign-out-of-skype-for-android), all you have to do, is open the menu on the top left, and you'll find a *sign out* button on the bottom of the menu.

You will then have an option to sign in using a different account.

Comment: I have no such page, because Skype start in the call history... but I figured it out.